# Can I implement different layers of an android app with different programming languages?

Tags: java, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to work on an android app that uses jetpack compose.I wanted to know if I can implement the ui layer in kotlin and the other layers in Java?

I googled this problem and didn't find anything

Comment: Yes you can, and as far as I know you can even mix them in the same file. You can read more about this [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mixing-java-kotlin-intellij.html) and [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html)

Answer (score -2):

Kotlin is an Java interoperable language, therefore, you can either call Java class methods from Kotlin file or vice versa.

Here are some links form official Kotlin language website to help you with your usecases.

[Calling Java from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html)

[Calling Kotlin from Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html)

Android Developers website also has an official [Kotlin-Java interop guide](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/interop).